# C# Panel or picturebox for drawing

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, picturebox

Im looking to draw a map of dots(coordinates), i want to be able to select these dots later on by clicking on them. Is it better to use a picturebox for this or should i use a panel?

**EDIT**

Im drawing the dots from an array of values

Comment: Better is to use WPF and `Canvas`.

Comment: which technology are you using? Winforms? WPF? etc... ?

Comment: Im using Windows Forms App

Comment: I added "winforms" in your question tags, it will be clearer.

Comment: Regarding the question, it depends. For example you can draw your image on a picture box and add invisible controls where your dots are located, and handle events on them. Or you can draw "visual" controls as your dots. It will depend of questions like : do you need to be able to add / remove dots at the fly ?

Comment: There are 2 area's, only when loading an area i need to draw the dots ( they will have to be drawn outside of the panel too so i must be able to scroll)

Comment: Use a **PictureBox**  has DoubleBuffer enabled so It's much better.

Just handle the Paint event of the PictureBox and do all your drawing in there.

Comment: Easiest approach:  draw them on a panel, track their spatial and size characteristics, and then react to mouse clicks that fall into those spaces.  If you need to actually make the dots do something, then they probably need to be controls of their own.  Pictureboxes, more panels, whatever...choose what provides the behavior the dots need.  So unless you need more behavior from the dots, just draw them.

Comment: i am currently thinking that it might be usefull to change to colour of a the selected dot or something, also i want to get the coordinates of the selected dot

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: i am currently working on a panel, i asked the question before i started to check what i could use best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a PictureBox, it's best to assign a Bitmap object to PictureBox.Image and then draw to the Bitmap, as that's how it's designed to work.

If you want to use Panel, you should use your own class that inherits from Panel so you can set the options as follows. It's probably the best option  if you need scrollbars:

```
public class Canvas : Panel {

    public Canvas() {
        ResizeRedraw = true;
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, tho is it possible to select items that i've drawn in the picturebox?

Comment: @user2928013 Yes, but there's a bit of work involved. When the control is clicked, use the mouse coordinates to figure out which dot was clicked (if any). You could then change its colour and redraw to show that it's been selected.

Comment: Will this be easier in a panel?

Comment: @user2928013 I suggest trying both. If you want scroll bars you'll need to put the PictureBox in a Panel anyway. But if you find you need to switch between different Bitmaps, then PictureBox would be more useful.